# How to extend the html5 <label> element to make a custom one?

Tags: html, label

In HTML5 we are allowed to define whichever element we want to, like for example:

```
<mycustomlabel attr1="...">
    <!-- contents whatsoever -->
</mycustomlabel>
```

Now I want `<mycustomlabel>` to look and feel just like a normal `<label>`. For the look part I can rely on CSS and I could flesh out tons of CSS rules to make it appear just like a `<label>`.

**BUT** a `<label>` also has a very specific behavior I want to see cloned in `<mycustomlabel>`: when it receive focus, its first focusable child gets focus instead. Moreover (and more important) if it gets clicked, that child gets the click.

I could program all that behavior in javascript (apart from not knowing **exactly** what are all the special behaviors a `<label>` has, but knowing that my new custom element should behave **exactly** as a `<label>` would). However I hate duplicating code, and all that implementation details are hiding somewhere inside the browser anyway.

**So how can I make my custom element sort of extend from `<label>`?**

Comment: I cannot get my head around to WHY you would need to use 99% of the label but for the 1% simply use something else. Why not use label for the 99% functionality it gives you and just customize it to the other 1% you do need extra. C'mmon.

Comment: @Ovidash Why? In 1 word: **framework**. I'm bound to a framework which for customizing components requires me to create new custom elements. My new component has to use 99.9999% of `<label>`, but it can't be a `<label>`. I've put great effort while describing my problem to not mention any framework, because it could scare people not used to that particular framework. Since the problem is restricted to HTML5 (I think) the problem is described as an out-of-the-blue html page which I happen to put some new custom element just because.

Comment: Did you find an answer

Comment: @MrKlein unfortunately not